# What is wrong of my solution for the Leetcode puzzle Sqrt(x)?

Tags: java, sqrt

I am working on the LeetCode question No.69 named sqrt(x)(https://leetcode.com/problems/sqrtx/). It asked me to return the square root of the integer also in another integer. Below is my solution.

```
public class Solution {
    public int mySqrt(int x) {
    int i = 0;
    if(x==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for(i = 1;i<x/2;i++)
    {
        if(((i*i)<=x)&&((i+1)*(i+1)>x))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return i;
   }
}
```

After I submit the code, all the test cases where x >= 2147395600 are all failed. When x = 2147395600, it is returning a 289398 instead of  46340, which is the right answer. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Ummm.... `int` vs `long`?

Comment: convert i and x to long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try my code:

```
public int mySqrt(int x) {
        long i = 0;
        long j = x;
        int mid = 0;
        if (x == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (x == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        while (i <= j) {
            mid = (int)(i + j)/2;
            if (x/mid == mid) {
                return (int)mid;
            } else if (x/mid > mid) {
                i = mid + 1;
            } else if (x/mid < mid) {
                j = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        return (int)j;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of int, use long. This is because int only goes up to 2147395600, while long goes much higher than that. However, the expense is that you would have to convert to long, then back to int.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but simply by add a typecast (long) in front of the i*i expression, I solved it. The problem lay with the fact that i*i was exceeding the limit of the value that can be held by int and hence a garbage value was being returned.

PS: This solution is super slow so do consider other solutions like Binary Search provided above.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared i as an int and trying to do sqaure of i, which will throw error as int cannot hold such large values, use long to declare i or caste it i to long. But why do this when you can do it in O(log n) using Binary Search.